# How to create outlined EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textfield, android-custom-view

I would like to customise textfield in Android.

When login activity shows up it will display normal text field as shown below:

[image: Text field when login activity loaded]

When user clicks on text field to input, text field should be displayed as:

[image: Text field when user click to input]

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Take a look at [Google Material Components text field](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with  **`Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense`**

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/customInputLayoutStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:hint="Enter your valid phone" />

  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Then your **customInputLayoutStyle** will be

```
<style name="customInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
 </style>
```